# Manually remote into a computer to assist a local user?

Tags: remote, remote-assistance

Is there a way to manually remote into someone's computer to control their computer in the below scenario?

For example, from time to time I have family/friends overseas asking for help with a computer problem. I normally ask them to install teamviewer so i can remote in and see what the problem is.

However, I assume there must be a 'manual' way I can do this while talking to them over the telephone and asking for the IP address for example?

99% of the time the person is on Windows 8.1 (or perhaps Windows 10 in future) but it would be great if there was an OS agnostic way of doing this.

Comment: You nned a commercial software as *TeamViewer*.

Comment: I remember reading that such commercial applications are just providing a nicely packaged way of doing what can be achieved anyway though - that's what I'm hoping someone can help clarify?

Comment: One of the biggest obstacles to do it manually is `NAT`. Commercial applications can manage NAT and will give you more security features

Comment: TeamViewer saves all the hassle of trying to punch through someone else's firewall. It's free for home use & as such it's not worth the bother of trying to DIY a distant firewall ruleset. It works Mac & Win, idk about nix.

Comment: It can be done with the native client but only on certain versions of Windows.  Services like TeamViewer work on any version of Windows.  You should update your question to make it clear you want only a native solution, since there is only one native solution, you are going to get an answer that basic mimics this comment.